# How to have excel recognize zero as a string?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to put data validation on a range of cells so that you can enter no more and no less than 9 characters in those cells. The problem is that SOMETIMES those 9 characters will be all number ... and that "number string" will start with a zero ... e.g. 012345678. Excel will remove the zero, as it recognizes that string as a number and my validation kicks in saying that I need to enter 9 characters into that field.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can enter the value with `'` in front : `'0123`

Comment: that's what I would do ...IF it was just ME using it... but this needs to be user friendly ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the range of cells as **Text**. This will prevent Excel from trimming leading zeroes.

[image: Screenshot of Format Cells dialog]

Comment: you know what ... I don't even know why I did not try that... I just feel stupid right now ;/ thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
=TEXT(Cellwithnumber,"000000000")
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if you format a range as text prior to typing in data (by right-clicking → format cells) or with something like

```
Dim c As Object
For Each c In Selection.Cells
    c.NumberFormat = "@"
Next c
```

or

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
```

Excel wont cut the leading zeroes.

If other users are using your sheet, you could protect the cell formats, so they don't accidentally change it back to numbers by, say, pasting data in with formats.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new cell and enter them as text formulas. Say the value you want to get the 0 from is in A1, enter your formula in a cell:

```
=TEXT(A1,"000000000")
```

That will show the leading 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use VBA:

```
rngTarget.NumberFormat = "@" ' rngTarget is a Range, can be e.g. ActiveCell or ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2) or ActiveSheet.Range("B8")
```